# I need to extract all the characters on the right side of a matching character using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

I wanted to extract all the characters that lie on the right side of the matching character using BigQuery.
eg:
Suppose I wanted to extract all characters right of '-'
then:

1. happy-holiday will give holiday
2. gogoa-gone will give gone

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Try [SPLIT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split):

```
SELECT SPLIT("happy-holiday will give holiday", "-")[OFFSET(1)]
```

or [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract):

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("happy-holiday will give holiday", r"-(.*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

SPLIT as mentioned by Sergey works fine.. or you can do it the old school way :)

```sql
    WITH sample_data AS (
      SELECT 'happy-holiday' as text
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'gogoa-gone' as text
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'hello-world' as text
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'i-am-back' as text
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'hey-whatever is after the dash' as text
    )
    
    SELECT text
    , instr(text, '-', -1) as dash_position
    , substr(text, instr(text, '-', -1)+1, length(text)) as substr
    FROM sample_data
```

Results:

```
    TEXT                            DASH_POSITION   SUBSTR
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    happy-holiday                   6               holiday
    gogoa-gone                      6               gone
    hello-world                     6               world
    i-am-back                       5               back
    hey-whatever is after the dash  4               whatever is after the dash
```